# zbar - scanner frame, how to make it in landscape

Tags: ios, camera

I have issue in setting the camera/scanner in landscape mode, even i change the screen to landscape, but the camera/scanner still appears to be in vertical.

may i know what should be done to fix this ? on the camera APi or should change on the zbar library ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set the orientation mask for the reader:

```
reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;
```

you can edit the mask in ZBarReaderViewController:

```
// orientation set support
#define ZBarOrientationMask(orient) (1 << orient)
#define ZBarOrientationMaskAll \
(ZBarOrientationMask(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) | \     
ZBarOrientationMask(UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) | \
ZBarOrientationMask(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) | \
ZBarOrientationMask(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
```